# WSO2 DAS Metric DB size increasing

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

In our production installation, WSO2 DAS 2.0 (part of WSO2 APIM) has been running for past 2 months, we noticed the size of index staging queues folders size is constantly increasing. Is currently over 800 MiB.

Here is the log

```
ubuntu@wso2das:/opt/wso2am-analytics-2.0.0/repository/data/index_staging_queues$ ls -1 | xargs du -sh 
68M 0P
68M 0S
33M 1P
33M 1S
112M    2P
112M    2S
87M 3P
87M 3S
95M 4P
94M 4S
30M 5P
30M 5S
```

Please help how do we reduce the size, as we afraid it may run out of disk space. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can purge the data by schedule job using data purging option of DAS[1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Purging+Data

Comment: Thanks you. There are over 60 tables listed under table name field, which one should I configure for purging to reduce the above data directory size (2S/2P..)?